# How can I connect the backpack to my character?

Tags: animation, armature, parent

I want the backpack model to move with the equipped human model. How exactly can I do this? I also want the bag to be able to rotate in any direction I want with the human model.

[image]

Comment: An easy way would be to rig the straps to the rig of the character. And for the bag you could make seperate bones. Is that an option?

Comment: Yes I can copy extra bones, but I don't know how to attach the backpack to the bone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As DarkSoul says, switch your armature to *Edit* mode, create a bone for the bag itself: Duplicate a bone of the spine, put it where the bag is, parent it to the spine top bone with the *Keep Offset* option:

[image]

Now back to *Object* mode, select the bag object, shift select the armature, switch it to *Pose* mode, select the bag bone, and parent to > *Bone*:

[image]

Or you could make the bag part of the character object, select all its vertices, assign them to a vertex group that has the same name as the bag bone. The bag will automatically follow the bone as there's an *Armature* modifier that links the character to the armature.

Comment: Your instructions work, but how can I copy all vertex groups? Because the number of bones is too many and their names are too long.

Comment: What do you mean by "copy all vertex groups"? If you want to join the bag to the character (second solution), select the bag, shift select the character, and Ctrl J. Then create a new vertex group, give it the same name as the new bone (bag bone), and assign all the bag vertices to this vertex group.

Comment: Both methods work, thanks.